# How to pass matrix as paramter in pthread_create() function?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, operating-system, pthreads

I have just started with O.S programming and was exploring threads. I want to multiply 2 matrices and get their product using the pthread_create(), pthread_join() and pthread_exit() functions. However, pthread_create() takes input as void* whereas, I want to pass an int** parameter.

I already tried:

1. Passing m3 [my resultant matrix] in the pthread_create() function by typecasting it as (void*) and then typecasting it back to (int**) in my threadMultiply function but that didnt work
2. Putting m1,m2,m3 as global variables but that too gave me errors.

I am very confused and don't know how to approach this anymore. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int** alloc(int, int);
void display(int**, int, int);
void* threadMultiply(void* para);

int main()
{
    int r1,c1,r2,c2,r3,c3;  // rows and columns of each matrix
    int **m1, **m2, **m3;   // all 3 matrices

    // took inputs for r1,c1,r2,c2
    m1=alloc(r1,c1);
    printf("Enter the %d elements of the first matrix\n", r1*c1);
    for(int i=0;i<r1;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<c1;j++)
            scanf("%d", &m1[i][j]);
    m2=alloc(r2,c2);
    printf("Enter the %d elements of the second matrix\n", r2*c2);
    for(int i=0;i<r2;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<c2;j++)
                scanf("%d", &m2[i][j]);
    display(m1, r1, c1);
    display(m2, r2, c2);
        
    if(c1 != r2)
    {
        printf("\nMatrices cannot be multiplied, check dimensions");
        return 0;
    }
        
    r3 = r1;
    c3 = c2;
    m3=alloc(r3,c3);
    int MAX_THREADS = r3*c3;
    pthread_t threads[MAX_THREADS];
 
    // Creating threads. 
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++) 
    {
        int *p;
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, threadMultiply, (void*)(p));  //variable 'i' is of type int however function takes parameter of type void* so we have to do type-casting
    }
     
    // joining and waiting for all threads to complete
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++)
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);   
        
        printf("\nThe resultant matrix is:");
        display(m3, r3, c3);
        
return 0;
}

int** alloc(int row, int col)
{
    //dynamic memory allocation for first 2 matrices
    int **m=0;
    m=(int**)malloc(row*sizeof(int*));

    for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        *(m+i)=(int*)malloc(col*sizeof(int));
    }
    
return m;
}

void *threadMultiply(void *para)
{
    int i,j,k;
    for(i=0;i<r1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<c2;j++)
        {
            m3[i][j] == 0
                for(k=0;k<c1;k++)                  
                    m3[i][j]+=m1[i][k] * m2[k][j];
        }
    }
    printf("thread finished ...");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

### EDIT:

So after reading the comments, I tried this again. The code compiles but gives me a segmentation fault and doesn't display the second matrix

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct matrix {  // using struct to reference 2 matrices in the threadMultiply function
    int r1, c1, r2, c2;
    int **m1;
    int **m2;
}mat;

int** alloc(int, int);
void display(int**, int, int);
void accept(int**, int, int);
void* threadMultiply(void* para);

int main()
{
    int r1,c1,r2,c2,r3,c3;  // rows and columns of each matrix
    int **a, **b, **c;  // all 3 matrices
    long int *ret_value;    //using long int, since int cannot be type casted to void
    mat *m;
    printf("Enter the number of rows and columns(m x n) of the first matrix\n");
        printf("Rows=");
        scanf("%d", &r1);
        printf("Columns=");
        scanf("%d", &c1);
        a=alloc(r1,c1);
        printf("Enter the %d elements of the first matrix\n", r1*c1);
    accept(a,r1,c1);
        printf("Enter the number of rows and columns(m x n) of the second matrix\n");
        printf("Rows=");
        scanf("%d", &r2);
        printf("Columns=");
        scanf("%d", &c2);
        b=alloc(r2,c2);
        printf("Enter the %d elements of the second matrix\n", r2*c2);
    accept(b,r2,c2);
    printf("\nThe first matrix is:");
    display(a, r1, c1);
        printf("\nThe second matrix is:");
        display(b, r2, c2);
    
        if(c1 != r2)
        {
            printf("\nMatrices cannot be multiplied, check dimensions");
            return 0;
        }
        
        r3 = r1;
        c3 = c2;
        c=alloc(r3,c3);
        m->m1 = a;
    m->m2 = b;
    m->r1 = r1;
    m->c1 = c1;
    m->r2 = r2;
    m->c2 = c2;
    
    // Creating one thread for each operation
    int MAX_THREADS = r3*c3;    
    pthread_t threads[MAX_THREADS];
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++) 
    {
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, threadMultiply, (void*)(&m));  
    }
     
    // joining and waiting for all threads to complete
    for(int i=0;i<MAX_THREADS;i++) 
    {
        for(int j=0;j<r3;j++) 
        {
            for(int k=0;k<c3;k++)
            {
                //joining all the threads and retreiving value in ret_value
                if(pthread_join(threads[i],(void **) &ret_value) != 0)
                    perror("\nThread join failed.\n");
                c[j][k] += (long int)ret_value;   // int doesn't work here for some reason
            }
        }
    }
        
        printf("\nThe resultant matrix is:");
        display(c, r3, c3);
        
return 0;
}

int** alloc(int row, int col)
{
    //dynamic memory allocation for first 2 matrices
    int **m=0;
    m=(int**)malloc(row*sizeof(int));

    for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
        *(m+i)=(int*)malloc(col*sizeof(int)); //m+i so that we can access all the rows by incrementing value of i. (m+i) = m[i]
    
return m;
}

void display(int **m, int r, int c)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        printf("\n[");
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            if(j<c-1)
            {
                printf("%d\t", m[i][j]);
            }
            else 
            {
                printf("%d]", m[i][j]);
            }

        }
    }
}

void accept(int **a, int row, int col)
{
    int i, j;
    printf("Enter the elements\n");

    for(i = 0; i < row; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < col; j++)
            scanf("%d", (*(a + i) + j));  //same as a[i][j]
}
void *threadMultiply(void *para)
{
    mat *m = (mat*)para;
    int i = m->r1;
    int j = m->r2;
    int k = m->c2;
    long int return_val = m->m1[i][k] * m->m2[k][j];
    printf("\nThread finished ...");
    pthread_exit((void *) return_val);
}
```

Comment: This code does not show what you tried passing as a matrix, as instead you are passing a useless pointer to `p`. You don't need to cast to a `void *`. You do need to cast `para` to `int **` within your thread function.

Comment: Your thread function is referencing `m1`, `m2`, and `m3` but they're not defined in that context so this shouldn't compile.  You're also not using the function's parameter or passing it anything meaningful.  Please show one of your actual attempts with input, expected output, and actual output.

Comment: You pass to `pthread_create` a pointer to a pointer to `mat`. But in the thread function, you cast `para` to a pointer to `mat`. Spot the difference? **Note:** this comment belongs to the edited code. **Hint:** Read and try to understand the recommendation in my answer below.

Comment: And you declare `mat *m` (pointer to mat) but never assign a storage for it. But some lines below you dereference `m`.

Answer (score 0):

**Recommendation**: [Pointer declaration (cppreference.com)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/pointer)

There in the sections,

**Explanation**

> Pointers are used for indirection, which is a ubiquitous programming technique; they can be used to implement pass-by-reference semantics, to access objects with dynamic storage duration, to implement "optional" types (using the null pointer value), aggregation relationship between structs, callbacks (using pointers to functions), generic interfaces (using pointers to void), and much more.

**Pointers to void**

> Pointer to object of any type can be implicitly converted to pointer to void (optionally const or volatile-qualified), and vice versa:
>
> ...
>
> Pointers to void are used to pass objects of unknown type, which is common in generic interfaces: malloc returns void*, qsort expects a user-provided callback that accepts two const void* arguments. pthread_create expects a user-provided callback that accepts and returns void*. In all cases, it is the caller's responsibility to convert the pointer to the correct type before use.

---

**How does this apply to your code**

In your main function:

```
// Creating threads. 
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++) {
    int *p; // <- WARNING: pointer to int is uninitialized
    pthread_create(
        &threads[i], 
        NULL, 
        threadMultiply, 
        (void*)(p) // <- here you don't have to cast to void*
    );
}
```

The pointer `p` is uninitialized. Assign to `p` the address of any object you want to pass as argument (parameter) to the thread starting function.

Since you can pass only one argument, there is a problem if your multiply function requires three matrices (and their row and col counts). Therefore, you can pack the information into a struct.

**Example**:

```
//global
struct arg {
    int r1, c1, r2, c2, r3, c3;
    int **m1;
    int **m2;
    int **m3;
};

int main()
{
    //...

    struct arg p = {
        r1, c1, 
        r2, c2, 
        r3, c3, 
        m1, m2, m3
    }; //for demonstration purposes only, 
       //normally you would have to allocate a struct for each thread

    pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, threadMultiply, &p); //need address of operator

    //...

}
```

In order to avoid the introduction of a new struct, you can of course declare all the variables global, but with the struct you can pass different parameters to different threads (simultaneously).

Then the multiply function:

```
void *threadMultiply(void *para)
{
    struct arg *p = para; //implicit cast
    int r1 = p->r1;
    int c1 = p->c1;
    //...
    int **m1 = p->m1;
    //...
    //do your multiplication
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try this and let you know

Comment: I edited the code. Gives me segmentation fault now